# How to flip the webcam video on canvas without inverting the texts written in the canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, draw

I flipped a webcam stream to make it mirrored using `ctx.translate()` and `ctx.scale()` but it also does flip everything else drawn on the canvas. Is there a way to flip the webcam video but not the other drawings on the canvas like texts?

Here is the code I am currently using (excerpt):

```js
const setupcamera = () => {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      video: { width: 600, height: 400 },
      audio: false,
    })
    .then((stream) => {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    });
};

const detectpose = async () => {
  const poses = await detector.estimatePoses(video, false);

  console.log(poses);
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 600, 400);

  ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillText(po, elbowx, elbowy);

setupcamera();

video.addEventListener("loadeddata", async () => {
  ctx.translate(600, 0);
  ctx.scale(-1, 1);
  detector = await poseDetection.createDetector(
    poseDetection.SupportedModels.MoveNet
  );
  setInterval(detectpose, 20);
});
```

I thought about drawing a new canvas over the flipped canvas but if possible I would like to draw everything on the same canvas.

Comment: Can you share your code of where you draw the webcam onto the canvas, as well as the code where you draw text over it?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code and added the relevant parts. Please Let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: Is it possible to put a `div` above the canvas, and then set the text to the `div`?

Comment: @TheKNVB nice idea didnt think of that. Will try

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the context's matrix-transform during the drawing.
First you scale and translate the context, then you draw your video, here you reset the context's matrix before finally drawing the text.

```js
// using a video file because SO can't use gUM
const video = document.createElement("video");
video.muted = true;
video.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
video.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm";

// when available video.requestVideoFrameCallback is the best
const requestFrame = (cb) => {
  if(video.requestVideoFrameCallback) {
    return video.requestVideoFrameCallback(cb);
  }
  return requestAnimationFrame(cb);
};
video.play().then(() => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "800 90px sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  
  requestFrame(draw);

  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // vertical-flip
    ctx.scale(1, -1);
    ctx.translate(0, -canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    // reset the transform-matrix
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillText("Some text", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    requestFrame(draw);
  }
}).catch(console.error);
```

```css
canvas { max-height: 100vh }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it